# Entire function that maps real axis to unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis

Question: Determine the most general entire function $f$ having the property $|f(z)|=1$ when $\text{Im}(z)=0$.

One possible class of such functions is
$$
f(z)=e^{icz}
$$
with $c\in\mathbb{R}$ is a constant. But how to find other functions or how to prove all the entire function has such a form?

Comment: For any entire function $g$ which maps the real line into itself (like $\sin z, \cos z$) etc $e^{ig(z)}$ has this property.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy But how to show that functions having such form characterize all entire functions having such property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Claim: $f$ is entire and maps $\mathbb R$ to $\{|z|=1\}$ iff $f=e^{ig}$ for some entire $g$ that is real on $\mathbb R.$

Proof: Let's concentrate on $\implies,$ since the other direction is clear.

Since $f$ is entire, so is $\overline {f (\overline z)}.$ Hence $f(z)\overline {f (\overline z)}$ is entire. The hypothesis implies the last function is $1$ on $\mathbb R,$ hence it is $1$ everywhere. Therefore $f$ is never $0$ on $\mathbb C.$

It follows that $f=e^h$ for some entire $h.$ Again using $|f|=1$ on $\mathbb R,$ we see $\text { Re }h=0$ on $\mathbb R.$ Letting $g=-ih,$ we see $f = e^{ig},$ with $g$ real valued on $\mathbb R.$

Comment: Thank you very much!